# Cygnus: Bad HTTP notification (curl/7.29.0 user agent not supported)

Tags: fiware, iot, fiware-cygnus

I installed cygnus version 0.8.2 on Fiware instance basing on the image **CentOS-7-x64** using:

```
sudo yum install cygnus
```

I configured my agent as the following:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = mongo-sink 
cygnusagent.channels = mongo-channel 

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mongo-channel 
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# OrionMongoSink configuration
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoSink
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
# FQDN/IP:port where the MongoDB server runs (standalone case) or comma-separated list of FQDN/IP:port pairs where the MongoDB replica set members run
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = 127.0.0.1:27017
# a valid user in the MongoDB server (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username = 
# password for the user above (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password =
# prefix for the MongoDB databases
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = kura_
# prefix pro the MongoDB collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = kura_
# true is collection names are based on a hash, false for human redable collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.should_hash = false

#=============================================
# mongo-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

I tried to test it locally using the following curl command:

```
URL=$1

curl $URL -v -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "Fiware-Service: qsg" --header "Fiware-ServicePath: testsink" -d @- <<EOF
{
    "subscriptionId" : "51c0ac9ed714fb3b37d7d5a8",
    "originator" : "localhost",
    "contextResponses" : [
        {
            "contextElement" : {
                "attributes" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "temperature",
                        "type" : "float",
                        "value" : "26.5"
                    }
                ],
                "type" : "Room",
                "isPattern" : "false",
                "id" : "Room1"
            },
            "statusCode" : {
                "code" : "200",
                "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

but I got this exception:

```
2015-10-06 14:38:50,138 (1251445230@qtp-1186065012-0) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler.getEvents(OrionRestHandler.java:150)] Starting transaction (1444142307-244-0000000000)
2015-10-06 14:38:50,140 (1251445230@qtp-1186065012-0) [WARN - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler.getEvents(OrionRestHandler.java:180)] Bad HTTP notification (curl/7.29.0 user agent not supported)
2015-10-06 14:38:50,140 (1251445230@qtp-1186065012-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet.doPost(HTTPSource.java:186)] Received bad request from client. 
org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPBadRequestException: curl/7.29.0 user agent not supported
    at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler.getEvents(OrionRestHandler.java:181)
    at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet.doPost(HTTPSource.java:184)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Any idea of what can be the cause of this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygnus version <= 0.8.2 controls the HTTP headers, only accepting user-agets starting by `orion`. This has been fixed in 0.9.0 (this is the particular [issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/493)). Thus, you have two options:

- Avoiding sending such a user-agent header. According to the `curl` documentation, you can use the `-A, --user-agent <agent string>` option in order to modify the user-agent and sending something starting by `orion` (e.g. `orion/0.24.0`).
- Moving to [Cygnus 0.9.0](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/releases/tag/release-0.9.0) (in order to avoid you have to install it from the sources, I'll upload along the day a RPM in the FIWARE repo).